# Find the shortest prefix T of string S, such that S is a prefix of T^n

Tags: string, algorithm, prefix

The general idea we used was using a greedy algorithm that checked the remaining of the string and made comparisons.

This idea didn't work, and the general idea is probably using some sort of suffix tree or KMP algorithm, but everything I try fails.

Can anyone help please?

P.S:
T^n is the prefix times n, as n is the length of the string and the the string letters are between is[1..n]

Comment: What's `t^n` in the question?

Comment: T repeated n times. The statement means find the shortest prefix that repeated some number of times covers S  completely(and there is possibly some leftover)

Comment: T^n, sorry for misstype. its the prefix times n, as n is the length of the string and the the string letters are between is[1..n]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use rolling hash just like in [Rabin karp algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm). First double S so that you are sure that T^n is prefix of S*S.

Next iterate over the length of T. For each length you may compute the hash code of T^n in logarithmic complexity(quite similarly to binary exponentiation). Also after a linear precomputation over S*S you may find the hash code of each of its substrings in constant time(you need one more array that contains the hashes of all its prefixes and one more that contains the powers of the prime you are using for hashing). So you may check for each length if T^n == SUBSTRING(S^2, n * LENGTH_OG(T)) in O(log(n)) (here you should think a bit how to make the time to compute the hash of t constant for each iteration). So the overall complexity of the method proposed will be O(LENGTH(S) * Log(LENGTH(S))).

Hope this helps.

EDIT: I believe I have found a linear solution to the problem. It is based on KMP just as you state. After computing the failure function for your string observe its values. For instance for the case:

```
string s = "abcdababcdababcdababcdababc";
```

The values are as follows:

```
   a     b     c    d    a    b    a    b    c    d    a    b    a    b    c    d    a    b    a    b    c    d    a    b    a    b    c  
 -001  -001  -001  -001  000  001  000  001  002  003  004  005  006  007  008  009  010  011  012  013  014  015  016  017  018  019  020
```

Take a look at the value you have at the final index. I believe if you subtract it from the length of S and then subtract one more, you will get the length of the shortest repeated substring. In this example you have `27 - 20 - 1 = 6`. It is easier to observe in the case I show above - when the failure function ends with sequence of values from 0 to 20. But in fact if you have some other values that end with 20, then 0 to 20 will again be valid values for the failure function it will simply be skipping over some of the possibilities. Hope this makes sense. This algorithm is linear.

Comment: Creating T^n at least takes Omega(n) and creating it Omega(n) times causes to Omega(n^2) solution.

Comment: the main idea of the question is to find something probably in linear runtime, thats why i offered the suffix-tree or the KLP algorithm for strings

Comment: @SaeedAmiri you do not create T^N you only compute its hash and this can be done in the complexity I describe.

Comment: I don't know how you want compute T^n's hash in logn? would you describe it more?

Comment: Let's assume you compute the hash of T in constant amortized time(this is true because once you have the hash of T you may compute the hash of its prefix that is lacking the last char in constant time so for all T-s you require O(N) operations). Now having the hash of T you compute the hash of T^2 in constant time:
`hash(T) *prime_power(length(T)) + hash(T)`. Once you have this take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring

Comment: the main idea is to find a solution in O(n) time.

Comment: @R.A I believe I have described a linear solution using KMP